# Transform Map using Guava

Tags: java, guava

I have a Group object which has list of elements like below.

```
class Group {
    List<E> elements;
    public List<E> getElements() { return elements; }
}
```

I have Map object represented as below.

```
Map<Group, Double> groups = with some values....
```

I have a another Map as below.

```
Map<Element, Double> elementVal = with some values....
```

My Final map should be a

```
Map<Element, Double> = with some values
```

where value is multiplication of element's group value (`groups` map) * element's value (`elementVal` map).

I am looking for Map transformation preferably using `Guava` or any other cleaner way to this rather than exploding the maps.

thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship from `Group` to `Element`? Do the maps always have the same size? Are the keys ordered?

Comment: Can an `Element` be a member of more than one `Group`? If that is the case, what operation should be used to aggregate?

Comment: So You would like to multiply each `element` in each `group.elements` from `groups` by each `element` in `elementVal`? And You prefer Guava.

Comment: @reto, Group contains list of elements. Size of group map and element would be different. for ex, i have 100 elements. Then i will group this elements and create let say 10 groups.

Comment: @Boris, Element can be part of only one group.

Comment: @Kozi, yes, i would like to multiply group value with element value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

version with neasted loops

```
    @Test
    public void multiplyMaps() {
        Element e1 = new Element(1.);
        Element e2 = new Element(2.);
        Element e3 = new Element(3.);
        Element e4 = new Element(4.);

        Map elementVal = new HashMap();
        elementVal.put(e1, e1.d);
        elementVal.put(e2, e2.d);
        elementVal.put(e3, e3.d);
        elementVal.put(e4, e4.d);

        Group g12 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e1, e2));
        Group g23 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e2, e3));
        Group g34 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e3, e4));

        Map groups = new HashMap();
        groups.put(g12, e1.d + e2.d);
        groups.put(g23, e2.d + e3.d);
        groups.put(g34, e3.d + e4.d);

        for (final Map.Entry groupEntry : groups.entrySet()) {
            for (Map.Entry elementValEntry : elementVal.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(groupEntry.getValue() + "*" + elementValEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Then we apply little guava for inner loop;)

```
@Test
public void multiplyMaps2() {
    Element e1 = new Element(1.);
    Element e2 = new Element(2.);
    Element e3 = new Element(3.);
    Element e4 = new Element(4.);

    Map elementVal = new HashMap();
    elementVal.put(e1, e1.d);
    elementVal.put(e2, e2.d);
    elementVal.put(e3, e3.d);
    elementVal.put(e4, e4.d);

    Group g12 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e1, e2));
    Group g23 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e2, e3));
    Group g34 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e3, e4));

    Map groups = new HashMap();
    groups.put(g12, e1.d + e2.d);
    groups.put(g23, e2.d + e3.d);
    groups.put(g34, e3.d + e4.d);

    for (final Map.Entry groupEntry : groups.entrySet()) {

        Collection transform = Collections2.transform(elementVal.entrySet(), new Function, Object>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public String apply(@Nullable Map.Entry elementValEntry) {
                return groupEntry.getValue() + "*" + elementValEntry.getValue();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(transform);
    }
}
```

And finally convert outside loop plus use `FluentIterable`

```
    @Test
    public void multiplyMaps3() {
        Element e1 = new Element(1.);
        Element e2 = new Element(2.);
        Element e3 = new Element(3.);
        Element e4 = new Element(4.);

        final Map elementVal = new HashMap();
        elementVal.put(e1, e1.d);
        elementVal.put(e2, e2.d);
        elementVal.put(e3, e3.d);
        elementVal.put(e4, e4.d);

        Group g12 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e1, e2));
        Group g23 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e2, e3));
        Group g34 = new Group(Lists.newArrayList(e3, e4));

        Map groups = new HashMap();
        groups.put(g12, e1.d + e2.d);
        groups.put(g23, e2.d + e3.d);
        groups.put(g34, e3.d + e4.d);

        Collection> transform = Collections2.transform(groups.entrySet(), new Function, Collection>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Collection apply(@Nullable final Map.Entry groupEntry) {
                return Collections2.transform(elementVal.entrySet(), new Function, String>() {
                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String apply(@Nullable Map.Entry elementValEntry) {
                        return groupEntry.getValue() + "*" + elementValEntry.getValue();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        FluentIterable objects = FluentIterable.from(transform).transformAndConcat(new Function, Iterable>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Iterable apply(@Nullable Collection strings) {
                return strings;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(objects);
    }
```

Finally we have iterable object contains multiply results.

Of course it not solution of your problem becasue You will need apply one more transformation that take result from `objects` and match them with `Element`. It's not so hard because you should only change String to some kind of `Entry` (pair of objects).

Comment: Thanks much Koziolek for the detailed explanation. I will get back to you if i face any problem.

Comment: one more. In Your case, probably, You will need switch outer and inner loops. That because You need `Element` objects as a keys and after switch it will be easier to get them